# How to close sidebar on click for anchor using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sidebar and I want to close it when someone clicks on a link. In my code, the sidebar just closes for a millisecond when I click on an anchor element. How can I fix this without using jQuery?
The a tags are linking to a html page

JS:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('slidebar').getElementsByClassName('button')[0]
element.addEventListener("click", slide);

function slide() {
  document.getElementById('slidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}


var slidebar = document.getElementById('slidebar');
slidebar.addEventListener('click', handleMenuClick);

function handleMenuClick(event) {
  if (event.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) {
    document.getElementById('slidebar').classList.add('close');
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
#slidebar.active {
  left: 0px;
}

#slidebar.close {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: What are the a tags linking to? I am guessing that it is hiding the slidebar and then changing page, causing it to reappear in it's default state. If this is the case, you will need to store the state of the slidebar so that it will carry across the pages.

Comment: @frobinsonj the a tags are linking to a new html page, that's possibly the reason

Comment: In that case, I would recommend using [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store it's state. See the examples on the docs. You will need to update this whenever the slidebar opens/closes. You can then read this value to determine whether to show the slidebar or not. If you have some form of backend, cookies may be a better idea so that there is no delay in showing/hiding the slidebar.

Comment: Happy to help. If you run into any issues storing this value, there are plenty of other answers on this site that can help you out with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you prevent the default event when clicking the anchor tag. Otherwise, it might be re-rendering the page.

But based on your code, it looks like you're adding two functions onto the slidebar. One that closes and one that opens. Since the anchor tag that closes the slidebar is inside the slidebar - when you click it you first fire off the `handleMenuClick` function and then it bubbles up and fires off the `slide` function. So it closes and opens quickly.

Instead, add a third element that is used to open the slidebar and attach the `slide` function there.

Also, you don't need two classes for managing the state of hidden/not hidden. You can just provide a class that sets the display to none and toggle that class list. If you want transition effects you can do that in CSS

Maybe something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let slidebar = document.getElementById('slidebar')
  let collapseButton = slidebar.getElementById('close-button')
  let openButton = slidebar.getElementById('open-button')

  collapseButton.on('click', toggleClassList)
  openButton.on('click', toggleClassList)

  const toggleClassList = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    slidebar.classList.toggle('hidden')
  }
})


#slide-bar.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#slide-bar.hidden #close-button {
  display: none;
}

#slide-bar #open-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Obviously, it depends a bit on the code you have already written. But this is a basic example that would work. Just need to add the transitions for the sliding effect in CSS